# Why is sliverlist not working in my customscrollview?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

I am trying to add a sliverlist but it does not work for me, I am very new to using flutter and I am confused.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: const CustomScrollView(
    slivers: <Widget>[
      SliverAppBar(
        title: Text('Sample Slivers'),
        leading: Icon(Icons.menu),
        backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
        expandedHeight: 90.0,
        floating: true,
        pinned: true,
        snap: false,
      ),
      SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context) {}),
      )
    ],
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: _navigatorAppBar(),
  floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
  floatingActionButton: _buildFab(),
);
}
}
```

[image: img]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove the `const` keyword of the `CustomScrollView`.
2. Replace `SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context) {})` with:

```
SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {})
```

Full code:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: CustomScrollView(
    slivers: <Widget>[
      SliverAppBar(
        title: Text('Sample Slivers'),
        leading: Icon(Icons.menu),
        backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
        expandedHeight: 90.0,
        floating: true,
        pinned: true,
        snap: false,
      ),
      SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {}),
      )
    ],
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: _navigatorAppBar(),
  floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
  floatingActionButton: _buildFab(),
);
}
```